# How can I perform this query between related tables without using UNION?

Tags: sql, doctrine, union

Suppose I have two separate tables that I watch to query. Both of these tables has a relation with a third table. How can I query both tables with a single, non UNION based query?

Here's a theoretical example. I have a User table. That User can have both CDs and books. I want to find all of that user's books and CDs with a single query matching a string ("awesome" in this example).

A UNION based query might look like this:

```
SELECT "book" AS model, name, ranking 
 FROM book 
WHERE name LIKE 'Awesome%' 
UNION 
SELECT "cd" AS model, name, ranking 
  FROM cd 
 WHERE name LIKE 'Awesome%' 
ORDER BY ranking DESC
```

How can I perform a query like this without the UNION? If I do a simple left join from User to Books and CDs, we end up with a total number of results equal to the number of matching cds timse the number of matching books. Is there a GROUP BY or some other way of writing the query to fix this?

(EDIT: The reason I would like to avoid the Union approach is because this is actually a DQL query and Doctrine does not support UNION. If there's no way to do this without UNION, I'll go the native SQL route. In addition, the real query contains a bunch of additional columns that do not map as nicely against one another in the above example.)

Comment: what is wrong with the UNION approach?

Comment: and what do you mean by comparing a field on each table

Comment: I agree with KM.  If you think of the tables as a set of books and a set of CDs (as you should), it should be pretty straight-forward to see that a UNION of the two sets (in your example) is more appropriate.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but can we answer the question and not debate the merits of why I'm trying to do it this way? There are good reasons in my case to avoid UNION, which I left out to simplify the question.

If it's not possible to do this without UNION, that's different, and I accept that as an answer.

Comment: When you simplify it so much that UNION just jumps out as the proper technique, perhaps you've omitted details that would make the correct answer even possible to identify.

Comment: Why'd you tag it 'mysql' if this doesn't have anything to do with MySQL?

Comment: @David M: I would assume jeremy uses mysql. If so nothing wrong specifying exact database engine to get more precise answers (for example if it was tagged as postgres I would extend my answer to explain creating rules to update views)

Comment: Jeremy, what did you wind up doing? I have the exact same situation as yours (for different reasons not related to performance). I too would rather not refactor a bunch of code. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to avoid union one way is to create view.

EDIT: To [create view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) you have two options

In case your query is only for selecting records there should be no problem with

```
CREATE VIEW media AS
SELECT "book" AS model, name, ranking 
 FROM book 
WHERE name LIKE 'Awesome%' 
UNION
SELECT "cd" AS model, name, ranking 
  FROM cd 
 WHERE name LIKE 'Awesome%' 
ORDER BY ranking DESC
```

If you need view that can be updated then it might fly if you refactor:

- create table that will hold all the data AND media type
- create two views that will split data on media type (since these views are simple 1:1 queries to underlaying tables they should be updatable and you should be able to use them in ORM mapping or other SQL queries)

EDIT2: I forgot to comment on the fact that UNION ALL is a must over UNION unless you want MySQL to start building index on the disk every time you run the view/query (thanks HLGEM).

Comment: @KM, will that bother Doctrine?

Comment: Right!  You create this view:

CREATE VIEW V_BOOK_CD AS
SELECT "book" AS model, name, ranking
FROM BOOK
UNION
SELECT "cd" AS MODEL, name, ranking
FROM CD;

... and then you SELECT from the VIEW.

Comment: I have no idea, but the OP seems to not to want a UNION

Comment: This should work since the UNION is embedded in the view and then DQL won't have to use UNION.

Comment: @KM, I assume(!) Doctrine's ORM facilities can not work through UNION, but the VIEW might make it ok, hence the suggestion.

Comment: And while we're at it make the view use UNION ALL, it will be faster and there are clearly no overlapping records in the recordset so no need to check for duplicates.

Comment: I didn't think about this and it looks promising even if a UNION happens behind the scenes. See: http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/using-views-with-doctrine . I'll be back after I try this.

Comment: @HLGEM, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808828/sql-query-problem-how-to-merge-two-lists/2808916#2808916 :))

Answer (score 5):

Think of how you'd model this in an OO app.  You'd create a superclass that you extend for books and CD's, and your user would then own a set of `Collectibles`.  Any given object in that set is either a book or a CD (or other type of collectible) but it has exactly one of these subtypes.

You can do something similar with SQL, by creating a *table* corresponding to the supertype:

```
CREATE TABLE Collectibles (
  collectible_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id        INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id)
);
```

Then each subtype contains a reference to make it collectible:

```
CREATE TABLE Books (
  book_id   BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY
  book_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES Collectibles(collectible_id)
);

CREATE TABLE CDs (
  cd_id   BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY
  cd_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (cd_id) REFERENCES Collectibles(collectible_id)
);
```

Now you can do your query and be assured you won't get a Cartesian product:

```
SELECT u.*, COALESCE(b.book_name, d.cd_name) AS media_name
FROM Users u
JOIN Collectibles c ON (u.user_id = c.user_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Books b ON (b.book_id = c.collectible_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN CDs d ON (d.cd_id = c.collectible_id);
```

Comment: ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'schema.Users' doesn't exist :)

Comment: This is probably the proper solution :) It just would require some massive refactoring.

Comment: The other option is to bypass DQL and just use plain SQL, so you can use UNION.  When you use an ORM, you have to be prepared for the fact that the abstraction layer won't handle every scenario.

Comment: Ups, sorry for the error joke, I missed the Users table in the question and thought where did it spring from. :) +1

Comment: @Unreason: No worries.  It's just an example anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a compelling reason to not use a UNION, then just use the UNION.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this... the example assumes the third table is called User:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->select('c.cd, b.book')
  ->from('User u')
  ->LeftJoin('Cd c ON u.user_id = c.user_id AND c.name LIKE ?, 'Awesome%')
  ->LeftJoin('Book b ON u.user_id = b.user_id AND b.name LIKE ?, 'Awesome%');
$result = $q->execute();
```

Comment: This is where I am right now. The issue is that behind the scenes this query is really slow when we have a lot of matching books and cds as the actual number of items returned by the database is (# of matching CDs) * (# of matching books).

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is with the LIKE.... do you have an index on the "name" field in both CD and Book tables? Alternatively, rethinking the approach along the lines of Bill Karwin's suggestion might also speed things up a little.